# I need a to show that particular files are missing download it when he/she installs the exe file

Tags: batch, setup

I have created exe with the help of inno setup and it is running sucessfully. I need to show that "This particular files are missing please download it to run this files" and I have to show them he/she when he starts the intallation process. How do i do this

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here.

Comment: I'm not really sure what's being asked. Is this a batch script or an exe?

Comment: Try googling "inno setup prerequisites check"

Comment: i am trying to show in setup that "This particular file is missing in your computer" and I shd show this before he clicks finish button. @Smock